# QTextStream Comparing first character of each line in a csv file with a known variable?

Tags: c++, qt, csv

Title pretty much says it all, but I better be a little more specific so as not to confuse any one(including myself).

Been at this for two days not much success.
I have a CSV file and open/read it line by line with `QTextStream`. The line length is set to first character of each line only, line.at(0). It compares the beginning of each line with a know variable/integer. 
It works and the label does show "Match Found" but immediately afterwards, the app crashes. It never reaches the"No Matches Found".

The error I'm getting:

```
ASSERT: "uint(i) < uint(size())" in file ..\..\..\..\Qt\5.0.2\mingw47_32\include/QtCore/qstring.h, line 729
Invalid parameter passed to C runtime function.
Invalid parameter passed to C runtime function.
```

Any ideas? Anyone?

Oh yeah, here is the code to the function causing this headache.

```
void DialogToll::ReadAndCompare()
{


QString Number = ui->Tolls->text();


QFile filetoCompare("C:/Tolls.txt");

if(filetoCompare.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text))
{
        QTextStream stream(&filetoCompare);
        QString line;
        do
        {
            line = stream.readLine();
            if(line.at(0)== Number)
            {
                ui->label->setText("match Found!!!");
            }
        }while(!line.isNull());
        ui->label->setText("No match Found!");

}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You read file line by line, but it looks like some of the lines have zero length, so that your `line.at(0)` fails. I would improve your code in the following way:

```
[..]
QTextStream stream(&filetoCompare);
do
{
    QString line = stream.readLine();
    if (line.size() > 0 && line.at(0) == Number)
    {
        ui->label->setText("match Found!!!");
    }
} while (!line.isNull());
ui->label->setText("No match Found!");
[..]
```

Note that I check for the line's length before comparing its first character.

Comment: Would there happen to be a `line.isEmpty()` method?

Comment: Yes, `if (!line.isEmpty() && line.at(0) == Number)` will work too.

Comment: Thanks vahancho, works beautifully, but what is the advantage of (!line.isEmpty() && line.at(0) == Number) ?  Also, thanks xtofl, being tired I didn't realize I was overwriting the ui label after the loop had finished.

Comment: @Hank, `line.isEmpty()` looks nicer than `line.size() > 0` - that's all. Implementation of `QString::isEmpty()` calls `size() == 0` anyways.

Comment: Yes, that explains it. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Like @Vahancho said: you're not checking your line before accessing it's elements.  This will cause a crash for empty lines.

Did you realize that you overwrite the ui label after the loop
finished?  You can prevent that by returning early:

Next, you may want to use the power of `QRegexp` for this:

```
void checkMatch() {
....
  QRegexp expr("^"+ui->Tolls.text());
  do {
      auto line = stream.readLine();
      if (expr.exactMatch(line)) {
         ui->label->setText("Match");
         return; // <<<< early return
      }
  } while(!stream.atEnd());
  ui->label->setText("no match");
}
```

Comment: I will have to look into QRegexp. I don't know much about it. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Hank many of us don't know regular expressions too well.  We really should!  They're a powerfull tool in our dev-belts.